# Simplify matlab code to toggle var

Tags: matlab, toggle

I wonder if there's a simpler and nicer solution to toggle a variable between two values instead of (sure I can write a m-function but somehow I have the feeling there's something built-in in matlab, but I couldn't find it when googling for `matlab toggle`)

```
if(x == 0)
  x = 1;
else
  x = 0;
end
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just `x = 1 - x` would suffice ?

Comment: Oh yeah, it actually would be enough. I even would be for other numbers, like x = 5.5 - x --> x will be either 0 or 5.5! Only thing I can't think of: What if I want to toggle between two numbers which are NOT zero!?

Comment: If you want to switch from `a` to `b`: `x = (a+b)-x`.

Comment: Somehow I really like it! Very nice!

Comment: Oops, I got too stuck on using ~x-- that's obviously the best solution for arbitrary toggling.

Answer (score 7):

There's a NOT operator:

```
x = ~x;
```

If you want to toggle between 0 and some number a:

```
x = (~x) * a;
```

If you want to toggle between a and b:

```
x = (~(x - a)) * (b - a) + a;
```

Comment: Thanks you're right. This will actually work for the case posted above but NOT for any other number, like toggle between a and b with a != 0 and b != 0. Do you know any good solution for this too?

Comment: I updated the answer with something that can do that kind of toggle.

Answer (score 1):

```
x=1 % initialize the value
x=max([0  1]-x)   % toggle it
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @rmmh, though I think it is cleaner to cast it to logical first:

> b = logical(x);
>   x = ~x;